# chrome does not allow me to use pdf in img tag

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-s3, safari

The website that I am trying to build is meant to display pdf's that are stored in a s3 database. For example, a test url could be

```
https://homeworkupload.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1638152660205.pdf
```

However, when I use an img tag in the html to display this url it does not work for pdfs on chrome. This does work on safari.

code to display the url:

```
<img class="w-100pc whiteBacking" src=`${file.photoUrl[0]}` alt="">
```

On chrome this works when the url has a image ending. However not with a .pdf:
(url for the google logo image: https://homeworkupload.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1638145920232.png)

chrome:

[image]

safari:

[image]

Is there a way for me to fix this. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation that suggests it should work this way? Just because it works in Safari doesn't mean it is an HTML standard.

Comment: I am not sure if is supposed to work this way. I was more or less wondering if there is a work around. Or a way that would work for both chrome and safari.

Comment: You could use `<embed>` or an image screen shot.